# Gallery lock Application Firefox OS

Tags: firefox, web-applications, firefox-os

there is a Gallery lock Application?
ie when a person wants to see pictures , a password is obliged.
Thanks

Comment: If the phone is unlocked I do not believe the gallery is password protected.  You could log a bugzilla request here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox%20OS choose the Gaia::Gallery App

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox OS doesn't have a password lock in the gallery.
It has only a [Screen Lock password](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/set-screen-lock-firefox-os).